# Grunt and express.js server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, express, gruntjs

Currenty I'm using grunt with karma and jasmine to run my tests etc. for my Angular app.

I want to connect this app to a mongo database and was wondering what the best way to do this is. Should I keep using grunt and just connect to a database and use it all the way, or should I use an Express server as my main server connected to the database and run the tests with grunt?

Initially I want to publish this project to heroku, and I know you can do this by just adding a static server.js (wich I do not currently have) like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + ‘/public’));
app.listen(port);
```

and modify the gruntfile.js with this:

```
tasks
grunt.registerTask('heroku',
    ['compass:dist', 'autoprefixer', 'imagemin']);
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Just curious, why you want angular to connect to mongo db?

Comment: educational purposes. Is there any reason I shouldn't?

Comment: One is client technology and another server, that's why.

Comment: Im sorry... I cant make sense of what you said. What do you mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: What I meant is you should be writing separate tests for client (angular) and server(express). Mongo is server side so it can be tested along with server unit test cases. Since you are using jasmine you should be using jasmine spies to test ajax request. If how to test an ajax request is what you are looking at I can give you an answer.

Comment: My question was if I should just use grunt for everything as the tester and server (I see now that it may be a little silly) or use grunt for static server+testing and use express as main server connected to the mongo database. I was confused on how grunt and express should work togheter. I now see that a server.js with express as a production server and grunt for testing static files is a way to go.

Comment: I see, I feel you have slight misconception of what grunt is. Grunt is a task runner. It will run other commands when for each task. Say for example if you can compile css or minifiy js or combine images before starting server you can do it with grunt. But that does not mean grunt can do all those by itself. It will be using other libraries for those.

Comment: If you are using grunt to do testing you internally using jasmine or  karma js. Same when you say grunt serve you use express internally start server. So grunt does not connect to mongodb. It is express which connects to mongodb. You can write grunt tasks which will start mongodb and start express js and connect those two.

Should you use grunt? Yes ofcourse.

Comment: Thank you! The answer above is what I wanted (but I dont know how to mark it as the answer since its a comment...). I got confused when I read somewhere that you could do all this with grunt and wondered if it was possible. This line: 'You can write grunt tasks which will start mongodb and start express js and connect those two.' was what exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: I added it an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, I feel you have slight misconception of what grunt is. Grunt is a task runner. It will run other commands when for each task. Say for example if you can compile css or minifiy js or combine images before starting server you can do it with grunt. But that does not mean grunt can do all those by itself. It will be using other libraries for those.

If you are using grunt to do testing you internally using jasmine or karma js or something else. Same when you say grunt serve you use express internally start server. So grunt does not connect to mongodb. It is express which connects to mongodb. You can write grunt tasks which will start mongodb and start express server but grunt can not do either by its own.

Should you use grunt? Yes of course.